# Retrieving Data from Firebase and Printing them out

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one, and only one entry in my database. I have pushed it there using this code in androidstudio:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(singleMessage);
```

Each "singleMessage" consists of three fields:

```
public class SingleMessage {
    private String messageBody;
    private String messageAuthor;
    private String messageTime;
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to read that entry, and println all three fields. As easy as it sounds, I can't. Please help me. I have read similar questions/answers. Didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your database structure and use this:

```
DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("singleMessage").push();
```

**Why?** to be able to loop inside the random `push` key.

You can then do this:

```
db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String messagebody=data.child("messagebody").getValue().toString();
          String messageauthor=data.child("messageauthor").getValue().toString();
          String messagetime=data.child("messagetime").getValue().toString();
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};);
```

So first you add the reference to the listener and then, using the for loop, `data` will iterate inside the random `push` key of `singleMessage`

Comment: what was the error? Have you added the data there first?

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get object and use the values to update the UI
            SingleMessage singleMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(SingleMessage.class);
            // Do something with the data
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };);
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. I wrote an                 System.out.println(singleMessage.getMessageBody());
 to print out the message body, but got null pointer exception.